# Can topologies induce a metric?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let {X,T} be a topology, T the set of open subsets of X.

---

Definition: Three points x, y, z of X are in *relation N* (Nxyz, read "x is nearer to y than to z") iff

1. there is a basis **B** of T and **b** in **B** such that x and y are in **b** but z is not and
2. there is no basis **C** of T and **c** in **C** such that x and z are in **c** but not y.

---

For some topologies there are no points x, y, z in relation N, for example if T = {Ø,X} or T = P(X), but for others there are (e.g. for ones induced by a metric [my claim]).

---

Definition: A topology has *property M1* iff

(x)(y) ((z) (z ≠ x & z ≠ y) → Nxyz) → x = y

(This is an analogue of d(xy) = 0 → x = y, the best one I can imagine).

---

Definition: A topology has *property M2* iff

(x)(y)(z) Nxyz & Nyzx → Nzyx

(This is a kind of an analogue of d(xy) = d(yx), the best one I can imagine)

---

First (bunch of) question(s):

1. Properties *M1* and *M2* do not capture the whole of the corresponding conditions of a metric. Can anyone figure out "better" definitions (e.g. an analogon of x = y → d(xy) = 0)?
2. Can anyone figure out a *property M3* that is an analogue of the triangle equality?

If it can be shown that no such property M3 is definable, the following becomes obsolete.

If such a definition can be made, we define:

---

Definition: A topology has *property M* (read "induces a metric") iff it has properties M1, M2, M3.

---

Second question:

Which topologies have property M, i.e. induce a metric? Are these "accidentally" exactly those that are induced by a metric?

Comment: 
 I don't have an answer to your questions, but, more conventionally, there is a standard theorem about which topological spaces admit a metric. It's beautiful, though not too easy -- it's one of the key points of a Point-Set topology course. Look in Munkres's Topology, or here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space. Also, if you like these kinds of questions, I highly recommend you read either Bourbaki's "General Topology" or Kelley's "General Topology". Both have a few generalizations of metrics that you might enjoy (in particular, uniformities). 

Comment: Usage comments: "analogon" is much less common than the synonomous "analogue".  "Has property X" or "is in relation N" are poor choices.  Better is "Given a topology T on X, say that _x is closer to y than to z_ if....".

Comment: You might just want to learn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem .

Comment: All of the important information of a metric can be recovered by its induced uniform space. This carries both the topological information as well as the uniform information (uniform convergence, completeness, et cetera). I don't believe you can get all of the information you want with just a topology.  I am sure though, that one can only recover a metric up to topological equivalence.  

Comment: @Theo: I wanted to define the relation without bias. The proposed reading should be only a hint where the definition is aimed at.

Comment: Given the revisions at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9874/can-topologies-induce-a-metric-revised, I'm voting to close this question as no longer relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your condition 1 is satisfied for all triples $x,y,z\in X$ such that $z\not\in\{x,y\}$ if the space is [$T_1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).

Maybe reading a bit about uniform spaces and the corresponding metrizability results will be of help.

Comment: Picking up Aaron's answer: Might there be a way to sensibly restrict the class of "allowed" (= "sensible") bases.
What is T<sub>1</sub>?


Comment: There is no more reference to bases anymore in your (edited) answer. My follow-up question remains (sorry): what space is T_1=


Comment: I found the term T_1 linked and will follow this. Thanks!

Comment: In particular, HP Stricker's claim is patently false.

Comment: +1 for mentioning uniform spaces

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your "nearness" relation is the right definition to make.  It makes sense on the face of it, but for example I think you can generate the usual topology on the plane by tubular neighborhoods of half-circles.  For three points x,y,z on a line in that order, I don't think you get any relationship.  Using the usual disk basis you'd satisfy condition (1) for Nxyz, but you could violate condition (2) using the other basis I just suggested, if the tubular neighborhood is sufficiently small.

Comment: However, I too have wondered which topologies can be induced by metrics.  I think the first step in this direction would be to look for a topology which is <i>not</i> induced by a metric...

Comment: I thank you for this. Maybe the look for "unusual" bases should be sharpened (for beginners like me). Coming the standard way I thought only of disk bases. 
But maybe my line of thought can be "rescued"? 
If not: maybe it helps understanding the difference between topologies and metric spaces.

Comment: I don't know much about this stuff, but it looks like people who have commented on the original question suggest a wealth of resources for you to browse through...